# Free django application deployment

Tags: django, deployment

Is there any free deployment hosts for python/django apps. I have some personal and circle related application, I want to deploy that application with free of cost and use it with our circles. Is this possible?

Please anyone advise on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [dotcloud](https://www.dotcloud.com/) in [sandbox mode](https://www.dotcloud.com/pricing.html), or [heroku](http://www.heroku.com/) (you'll be limited to 10,000 database rows in free quota)

Comment: I've used only Heroku so far, and it's really easy to develop with. I'll give dotCloud a try.